# Image viewer on Windows that is similar to Geeqie

Tags: windows, images, image-viewer

I was originally on Ubuntu 16.04 and recently switching to Windows. One of the problems I have is I cannot find a `Geeqie` image viewer alternative. The main feature I need is

1. When my mouse hovers on top of a pixel, somewhere in the viewer it will show the corresponding color values (rgb) and pixel coordinates (xy).
2. The ability to turn off resampling when the image is zoomed in. Sometimes I need to examine pixel by pixel so no filtering is desired.
3. Lightweight.

I am pretty surprised that it's not trivial to find image viewers on Windows that satisfies these two condition. I tried the default windows photo, which satisfies non of them. I tried IrfanView, which only satisfies (2) and (3). There are Photoshop and Fusion that satisfies (1) and (2) but they are not lightweight nor free. Please recommend.

Comment: Did you find an answer? if so, can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

Hum. IrfanView actually shows you the pixel position and color when you click a point, so I think your requirement 1 is also covered.

Just Left Click on a point
[image]

You can probably complement the color selection using a color picker like http://www.color-picker.de/

With this color picker you also can complement Gimp.

For example, grabbing the color picker selector first to your image, and when you release the mouse you get the color and coordinates.

---

And not that lightweight but free is Gimp itself. If you choose the eyedroper it shows the pixel position and if you open the color window shows you the HEX, RGB or HSV values.

[image: Original Image Freepik]

Comment: Hmm how come my IrfanView shows nothing when I click a point, did you have to modify something in the settings to enable it?

Comment: Nop. I will post tomorow a screen capture

Comment: I have to hold the left click to view the pixel information and can't move around freely. It's not us convenient as geeqie

Answer (score 0):

This Javascript based tool does the job.

https://yangcha.github.io/iview/iview.html

You should be able to download the code and run it locally (haven't tried it personally).
Easily open your image and by hovering over pixels you'll get the X,Y coordinates and their associated pixel values in three R,G,B as shown in the sample screenshot below.

I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sure, edited my answer with more details.